# posting on user's friend wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api, post

i've built this application who keep in a database the uid of the users who used it.
when the administrator of the application is logged in to facebook and to the application,
he sees if a list of all the users who used the application, ordered by if they're friends with him on facebook or not.

the administrator has granted the publish_stream permission for my application.

i want do give the administrator an option to write a post or a link on the wall of a user which he is friend.

reading the graph api documentation i've found that i can POST to https://graph.facebook.com/uid/feed or  https://graph.facebook.com/uid/links a feed.
from some reason i'm not able to do so..
can some please tell me what is the way to do so and what are the parameters i need to send to there api functions?

Comment: What error are you getting when you try? What are you trying to post?

Comment: i'm just trying to post a message of behalf of my user.
i think i know what's wrong.. i'm trying to test it throw the Graph API Explorer, when connect as myself..
how do i pass the parameter of my appid in order to identify in api ?
i think that's what missing..

Comment: this is the error i'm getting...
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#240) Requires a valid user is specified (either via the session or via the API parameter for specifying the user.", 
    "type": "OAuthException"
  }
}

Comment: Are you posting with an app access token to '/me'? that won't work, you need to specify the user ID or use a user access token

Comment: i'm logged to the application as me with the publish_stream access token.
trying to POST to https://graph.facebook.com/friend'sid/link?acces_token=...
and i get the error wrritten above.. maybe i should add the appid to the the POST parameters ?

Comment: Are you posting to /OTHER_USER/link or /OTHER_USER/links ?
Are you absolutely sure you're using a user access token? make a call to /me with it to make sure, that error shouldn't happen with a user access token as far as I can tell

Comment: Im posting to /otheruser/links. And im sure im having the access token. Shouldnt i add somewhere the application id? Or grant_type?

Comment: Is it definitely the `access token` and not the `code` you have? I don't think i can debug this any further without the access token and API call you're making but I really don't recommend posting those publicly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Im posting to /otheruser/links.

You should post it to `/otheruser/feed`.  Facebook will automatically put your link into the link area.

Comment: I like this answer very short simple and understandable :)

Comment: can you please tell me what are the fields i should send within the POST request ?
i know i have the "link" "message" "description" etc.. but do i have to send my application id somewhere ? and if so - where ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/  scroll down to the `<h2>` tag of `feed` part

Comment: Facebook doesn't support this anymore https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/

Comment: Casey, welcome to the wonderful world of Facebook API development.  You have just pointed out one of the most basic tenants of Facebook's API.  Facebook changes their API and the way it works more often then you could imagine.  Many of my answers, correct at the time, are now worthless due to the ever changing Facebook API landscape.